# Backtracking algorithm for cell connections in a grid

Tags: c++, backtracking

The explanation might be confusing or long (or both), so please let me know if there needs to be any clarification.
I am currently designing a backtracking algorithm to find a solution for something similar to what a game of "snake" looks like.

The program will start with a 2D grid, where some of the cells are inaccessible (like an obstacle). The program then proceeds with a backtracking algorithm to connect `int x` sequence of cells into a string-like group, then repeats this process until all `int y` accessible cells in the grid are connected into `y / x` groups. There are no cases where `y` is indivisible by `x`.

To determine the cost of the group, there are certain priority on the direction of the connection. For simplification, I will only use 3 connection types, `double horizontal`, `double vertical`, and `double diagonal`, where `horizontal` has the lowest cost and `diagonal` has the highest.

I've spent numerous days on trying to come up with different backtracking algorithms, but none of them had worked so far.
Here's a rough sketch of what I have(actual code has lots of custom class involved, so it may cause a lot of confusions):

```
String_c Grid::backtracking(int x, int y, int tot_pnl_needed, String_c &str_orig){
    bool branch_found = false;
    String_c str_cur = str_orig;
    // set cell (x,y) as occupied. OCCUPIED is an enum value
    set_avail(x,y,OCCUPIED);
    str_cur.push_cell(x,y);
    if (str_cur.is_complete()) {
        return str_cur;
    }
    String_c str_tmp;
    std::priority_queue<String_c, std::vector<String_c>, compareString> queue;
    // if the neighboring cell is available, create a branch
    if (is_available(x+1, y)){ // right side
        tmp_str = backtracking(x+1, y, tot_pnl_needed-1, str_cur); 
        if (tmp_str == failed){ // assume that "failed" is a special String_c object. == operator is overloaded.
            set_avail(x+1,y,AVAILABLE); // AVAIL is an enum value
            tmp_str.pop_cell();
        }
        else{
            branch_found = true;
            queue.push(&tmp_str);
        }
    }
    // copy this selection code above for each different direction
    if (branch_found) {
        while (!queue.empty()) {
            // push all branches into the stack, which is a parameter of Grid class
            stack.push(queue.pop());
        }
    else return failed;
return stack.top();
```

This is a pseudo code for the minimum backtracking algorithm required. In actual program, if the algorithm hits `branch_found == false` at the end, it needs to flip the sequence of the String_c, then continue the backtracking until it finds no branch again. Again, after one backtracking algorithm is finished, it will be called again until all cells are occupied.

One thing to be noted is that even if a String_c is completed and is pushed to the stack, it may be reverted later if none of its branch had found a solution.

This is the first time attempting to program a backtracking algorithm, so it was really stressful even to come up with this (which still fails...)
If you are the expert at this matter, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: So a path finding algorithm?

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: It has some common, but not necessarily. I only specify the starting point, but the ending point can be anywhere in the grid.

Comment: The most common and likely clearest way is to use a recursive algorithm when you want backtracking. This way at every function call you have a new set of state related to the problem you are trying to solve. If that function solves the problem. Great. If not then it either moves forward (calling itself again) or pops from the stack (backtracking) signaling to itself that the problem remains unsolved (i.e. try a different route). Look into (simple) recursive divide and conquer algorithms about graphs or grids to get the idea.

Comment: @ceorron: The pseudocode above IS already a recursive algorithm, using a stack to store all successful branches.